# text box only displaying one word as value

Tags: php, html, textbox, echo

Can anyone help me understand why a text box won't display a whole string opposed to  just the first word? For example if the value of Name is "John Smith", the text box will display "John"

`echo "<td>" . "<input type = text name = name value =" . $record['Name'] . " </td>" ;`

Comment: Its textbox width. try to increase in css "style:width:200px;" and see

Comment: No, Musa had it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you did not quote your attribute value, without quotes spaces terminate the attribute value

```
echo "<td><input type = text name = name value =\"" . $record['Name'] . "\" ></td>" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

value=". $record['Name'] ."

Comment: Use special code formating