# HTML text form element only showing first word in PHP array

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

The following PHP should show "just a test", but is only showing "just". What am I doing wrong?

```
{echo "<p>Description: <input type='text' autocomplete='off' name='description' id='description' style='text-align: left; background-color: lightgreen; width: 80mm' value = ".$array["description"].">";}
```

Comment: The obvious question is, what is `$array["description"]`?

Comment: Sorry, the $array[] is a row of data from a SQL select statement, of which "description" is a field in the SELECT statement.

Comment: I'll try again **what is $array?**. What you think it is, may not always be what it is. So tell me what is $array, not what you think or want it to be, but what it actually is!

Comment: $description=strip_tags($array["description"]);
echo $description; // this returns "just a test"
echo "<p>Description: <input type='text' name='description' id='description' style='text-align: left; background-color: lightgreen; width: 80mm' value =". $description ."></p>"; // this returns "just" in the input box

Comment: Not sure I understand. I know that value of $array['description'] is 'just a test', but when used as the value in the HTML text input field, it only shows 'just'.

Comment: This solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466145/text-box-only-displaying-one-word-as-value

Answer (score 1):

`value = '".$array["description"]."'>"` You should use `'`

Comment: You need to put more context to your answer.

Comment: Tried that. Still only returns the first word in the phrase.

Comment: @WebOOK I don't think your answer has an impact on the output of OP.

Comment: @suvojit_007 I believe it does, but he/she has not explained the answer. That is the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/3tknz7sd/

Comment: @andreas Thanks Andreas.